# given current datetime how do i determine the the nearest time before and after from a given dateime array

Tags: java

Given a list of times, how do I get the nearest times in the past and the nearest time in the future in java: for example current is 2017-06-06T12:04:00 and the list  2017-06-06T11:00:00, 2017-06-06T11:30:00, 2017-06-06T12:00:00, 2017-06-06T12:30:00. In this case i am expecting the to get 2017-06-06T12:00:00 and 2017-06-06T12:30:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Parse the strings as date objects, for example a `LocalDateTime`, which needs to be `Comparable`.
- put them in an `TreeSet`
- use `TreeSet::floor` and `TreeSet:ceiling` to get the closest time

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. i am having hard time putting this together. would you kindly help me further: this is my pseudo code list of times TreeMap<LocalDateTime, Object> activeTimes = (TreeMap<LocalDateTime, Object>) map.get("times"); LocalDateTime currentTime = CurrentTime. how do i then compare these to get nearest past and future

Comment: You don't need a TreeMap, a TreeSet will be enough here. And to find the nearest date before and after, use the floor and ceiling methods. Note that current time is `LocalDateTime.now()`.